# Class generic DeleteView not working for model related to model

Tags: django

I have a page containing assignment questions.
Questions related to assignment is displayed on asisgnment details page with EDIT and DELETE anchor tags.
But after pressing delete I get an error : Reverse for 'CreateQuestion' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['assignment/(?P[0-9]+)/createQuestion/$']

views.py

```
class AssignmentDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Assignment
    template_name = "dashboard/assignment_list.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ViewAssignment')
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

class AssignmentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Assignment
    template_name = "dashboard/assignment_detail.html"

class QuestionDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'dashboard/assignment_detail.html'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('assignment_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.assignment_id})
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:assignment_pk>/DeleteQuestion/<int:pk>/delete', views.QuestionDeleteView.as_view(), name='DeleteQuestion'),
path('<int:pk>/createQuestion/', views.QuestionCreate, name='CreateQuestion'),
path('assignment/<int:pk>', views.AssignmentDetailView.as_view(), name='assignment_detail'),
```

assignment_detail.html

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Course:{{assignment.course }}</h1>

  <p><strong>Assignment:</strong> {{ assignment.number }}</p> 
  <p><strong>publish_date:</strong> {{ assignment.publish_date }}</p>
  <p><strong>deadline:</strong> {{assignment.deadline_date}}</p>
  <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px">
    <h4>Questions</h4>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Question Title</th>
          <th scope="col">Question Marks</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit Question</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete Question</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for question in assignment.question_set.all %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ question.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ question.marks }}</td>
          <td> <a href="{% url 'UpdateQuestion'  assignment.id question.id %}">Edit</a> </td>
          <td> <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="{% url 'DeleteQuestion'  assignment_pk=assignment.id pk=question.id %}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>

<a class=" btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'CreateQuestion' assignment.id %}">Add Question</a>
  </div>



{% endblock %}
{% block script %}

{% endblock %}
```

Models.py

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course,on_delete = models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    deadline_date = models.DateField()
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty,on_delete = models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Assignment {self.number}-{self.course}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this Assignment."""
        return reverse('assignment-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
class Question(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True , null = True)
    marks = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this book."""
        return reverse('question-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

[The Assignment detail page with questions associated with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isO8h.png)

Comment: You need to show the rest of the assignment detail template, in particular the part with the link to createQuestion.

Comment: Please check I have updated assignment detail template

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are doing. Why are you using `assignment_detail.html` for the delete question view? That view should use a specific template that shows a confirmation message in a form which posts back to itself to perform the delete.

Comment: I have added the screenshot please check. Help me please I  am fed up wasted whole day behind this. Question.ForeignKey = Assignment.ForeignKey=Coursehas2Foreingkey(Grade , Department) (This are how my models related to each pther)

Comment: I have no idea how that relates to my question. I can see the template already, but you didn't answer the question of why you have assigned *that same template* to the DeleteView.

Comment: so that after deleting i get the question list back.for example. 1)Click delete 2)confirm popup by javascript 3)page refresh and user get the new updated question list . I dont know ajax that is why  I have to choose this  way:(

Comment: But this is not how a delete view works. And there is no need for Ajax. As I said above, the template for the delete view needs to show the conformation form. Redirecting back to the question list is done by `get_success_url`, which you have already defined.

Comment: I can delete assignment from assignmentlist  and it works without confirm_delete html (attached the AssignmentDeleteView Code) with it but why cant it also work with Question ?      I also noticed a get method in my AssignmentDeleteView is it making any difference ?  I think thats the problem . should I add a Get method in my Questiondeleteview too ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to my code and added a get method and now its working as I wanted it to.
It would be great if someone point out any risk related it.Thank you all for your time in helping in my problem

here is the UPDATED code :

```
class QuestionDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "dashboard/assignment_detail.html"
   self.object.assignment_id})
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('assignment_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.assignment_id})
```